# How do i play a moveiclip from the library with a key press

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe, flash-cc

im trying to play a moveiclip from the library with a key press and i have as linked it but it still does not work (this is only a bit of the code there are event listeners and handlers in place and the character moves fine)

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, Move);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPress);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUp);

var aP:Boolean = false;
var dP:Boolean = false;
//creating a new Character_right instance
var character_right:Character_right = new Character_right(); 

function Move(vet:KeyboardEvent)
{
    if(aP)
    {
        char.x -= 5;
        char.scaleX = -0.55;
    }
    if(dP)
    {
        char.x += 5;
        char.scaleX = -0.55;
    }
}

function keyPress(evt:KeyboardEvent)
{
    switch(evt.keyCode)
    {
        case Keyboard.A:
        {
        aP = true;
        break;
        }
        case Keyboard.D:
        {
        dP = true;
        character_right.play(); 
        break;
        }
     }
}

function keyUp(evt:KeyboardEvent)
{
        switch(evt.keyCode)
    {
        case Keyboard.A:
        {
        aP = false;
        break;
        }
        case Keyboard.D:
        {
        dP = false;
        break;
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: ...you are executing `break` before `Character_right.play()`... of course it will not work.

Comment: What are you trying to do, is Character_right a movie clip?  Are you getting errors?

Comment: yeah it is a movieclip and i have AS Linked it and it says the following error:

Comment: Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 108, Column 20 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method play through a reference with static type Class.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this post](http://kirill-poletaev.blogspot.se/2010/07/smooth-character-movement-using-as3.html), with a nice tutorial about keyboard events, I believe will be important for you to understand the concept and implement on your logic.

Briefly it's something like the following example, but remember about to implement all necessary logic for your scope.

```
        var isRight:Boolean;
        var isLeft:Boolean;
        var isUp:Boolean;
        var isDown:Boolean;
        //creating a new Character_right instance
        var character_right:Character_right = new Character_right(); 

        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, downKeyHandler, false, 0, true);
        function downKeyHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT )
            {
                isRight = true;
            }
            if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)
            {
                isLeft = true;
            }
            if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
            {
                isUp = true;
            }
            if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
            {
                isDown = true;
            }
        }

        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, upKeyHandler, false, 0, true);
        function upKeyHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
            {
                isRight = false;
            }
            if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)
            {
                isLeft = false;
            }
            if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
            {
                isUp = false;
            }
            if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
            {
                isDown = false;
            }
        }

        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loopHandler, false, 0, true);
        function loopHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            if (isRight)
            {
                //do something here…
                                    character_right.play();
                            }
            if (isLeft)
            {
                //do something here...
            }
            if (isUp)
            {
                //do something here...
            }
            if (isDown)
            {
                //do something here...
            }
        }
```

Comment: this doesn't really help me with my question but ill edit my question so you can understand it better.

Comment: @Smadygrady, have a look now, I have just edited my answer and made some changes on your question as well

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are executing the function `Character_right.play()` after `break` and break stops the rest of the loop code from being executed, so execute `Character_right.play()` before `break`, for example:

```
function keyPress(evt:KeyboardEvent)
{
    switch(evt.keyCode)
    {
        case Keyboard.A:
        {
        aP = true;

        break;
        }
        case Keyboard.D:
        {
        dP = true;
        Character_right.play();
        break;
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: To anyone who reads this answer:  In the question, break was put before Character_right.play(), he simply edited his question.